# how to check if time is in between the time array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

can anyone tell how to do this...

i have two declare array and a variable ...

```
$check_start = array('5:00', '11:00');
$check_finish = array('8:00', '15:00');
$time =  "7:00";
```

and I have a loop that check if $time is between the two array...

```
foreach($check_start as $key => $value)
{   
    $newTime = date('h:i', strtotime($time));
    $timeStart = date('h:i', strtotime($value));
    $timeFinish = date('h:i', strtotime($check_finish[$key]));
    if($newTime > $timeStart && $newTime < $timeFinish) {                       
        echo "inBetween";
    }else {
        echo "not";
    }

}
```

and the output is

```
inBetween not
```

Now I want to display only one output: 
if there is atleast one in between the array.

```
then display only "inbetween".
```

please refer with the code..

Comment: Whats the problem? 7:00 is between 5:01 and 7:59 and not between 11:01 and 14:59.

Comment: @JasonK - sir I want only to check if 7:00 is between all the set of array. if its true then display only inbetween..

Answer (score 0):

Add a break after in the

```
echo "inBetween";
break;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $pass= 0;
foreach($check_start as $key => $value)
{   
$newTime = date('h:i', strtotime($time));
$timeStart = date('h:i', strtotime($value));
$timeFinish = date('h:i', strtotime($check_finish[$key]));
  if($newTime > $timeStart && $newTime < $timeFinish) {                       
   $pass++;
  }
}
if ($pass > 0){echo 'inbetween';}
```

Comment: hi.. ive tried but when I change $time = '14:00' it shows nothing... but 14 is between 11 and 15 right..